# Python3.6 checkbox, price options

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I got some code for a basic program I'm writing in IDLE with Python3.6. I want the user to select which options they want, either all 4, 1 or any combination in between, click 'Total' to find the sum/a.k.a the price of all selected options and display it in a messagebox. Using `Checkbutton`, `tkinter`, `MyGUI` etc.

I am totally lost in the `def do_this(self):` section as well with the `if` statements. Here's the code, any and all insight would be appreciated.

The way we are being taught is very very basic, and I want all the answers to be as basic as possible, the assignment is meant to be this way by design.

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.messagebox
class MyGUI:
    def __init__(self):
        self.main_window=Tk()

        self.main_window.geometry('300x300+100+100')
        self.main_window.title("Price Options")
        self.frame1=Frame(self.main_window, width=280, height=240)
        self.frame1.place(x=10, y=10)
        self.choice1=IntVar()
        self.choice2=IntVar()
        self.choice3=IntVar()
        self.choice4=IntVar()

        #want this price $20
        self.cb1=Checkbutton(self.frame1, text='Option1', font=('Arial',16),\
                             variable= self.choice1)
        self.cb1.place(x=40, y=40)
        #want this price $30
        self.cb2=Checkbutton(self.frame1, text='Option2', font=('Arial',16),\
                             variable= self.choice2)
        self.cb2.place(x=40, y=75)
        #want this price $40
        self.cb3=Checkbutton(self.frame1, text='Option3', font=('Arial',16),\
                             variable= self.choice3)
        self.cb3.place(x=40, y=100)
        #want this price $50
        self.cb4=Checkbutton(self.frame1, text='Option4', font=('Arial',16),\
                             variable= self.choice4)
        self.cb4.place(x=40, y=135)

        self.button1=Button(self.frame1, text='Total', font=('Arial', 16),\
                            command=self.do_this)
        self.button1.place(x=40, y=170)
        mainloop()

    def do_this(self):
        if self.choice1.get():
            #What to put
        elif self.choice2.get()+self.choice1.get():
            #What to put
        elif self.choice3.get()+self.choice1.get()+self.choice2.get():
            #Etc..
        elif 
            self.choice4.get() + self.choice1.get()+ self.choice2.get()+ self.choice3.get():
        #Etc..
        tkinter.messagebox.showinfo('Total', )#<----- What to put 


my_gui=MyGUI()
```

I think I am missing some variable or command or something, all the help I've come accross are deeper and higher skilled concepts that we havent touched on in class yet, I just want to wrap my head around this.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution to get you from where you are to where you want to be is to set the `onvalue` and `offvalue` options on the `Checkbutton` instances.  That is, rather than have `self.choice1.get()` return a boolean value, have it return 0 if it's unchecked or it's price (20) if it is checked.  Then you can simply sum the variables rather than test them:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.messagebox

FONT = ('Arial', 16)

class MyGUI:
    def __init__(self):
        main_window = Tk()

        main_window.geometry('300x300+100+100')
        main_window.title("Price Options")

        frame = Frame(main_window, width=280, height=240)
        frame.place(x=10, y=10)

        self.choice1 = IntVar()
        self.choice2 = IntVar()
        self.choice3 = IntVar()
        self.choice4 = IntVar()

        # want this price $20
        cb1 = Checkbutton(frame, text='Option1', variable=self.choice1, \
            onvalue=20, offvalue=0, font=FONT)
        cb1.place(x=40, y=50)

        # want this price $30
        cb2 = Checkbutton(frame, text='Option2', variable=self.choice2, \
            onvalue=30, offvalue=0, font=FONT)
        cb2.place(x=40, y=75)

        # want this price $40
        cb3 = Checkbutton(frame, text='Option3', variable=self.choice3, \
            onvalue=40, offvalue=0, font=FONT)
        cb3.place(x=40, y=100)

        # want this price $50
        cb4 = Checkbutton(frame, text='Option4', variable=self.choice4, \
            onvalue=50, offvalue=0, font=FONT)
        cb4.place(x=40, y=125)

        button = Button(frame, text='Total', command=self.do_this, font=FONT)
        button.place(x=40, y=170)

        mainloop()

    def do_this(self):
        total = self.choice1.get() + self.choice2.get() + \
            self.choice3.get() + self.choice4.get()
        tkinter.messagebox.showinfo('Total', str(total))

my_gui = MyGUI()
```

This may not be the *best* solution to your problem, but it is *very basic*.

Comment: Thanks for the help, onvalue/offvalue was not in my notes, glad you put that up there for me. What makes it possible to create buttons without 'self.' at the beginning, is it because def __init__(self):? We are still being taught to write all the code out, helps most of the time but efficiency when it can be learned is goes a long way as long as I understand the steps. Again thanks alot.

Comment: @ragnerman, in this example, the `self` variables are the ones that show up in multiple methods.  I removed `self` from ones that didn't and made them local to the method.  Just to simplify the example.  If when adding more methods you find you need some of these values, you can add back the `self` and make them belong to the instance.